# Error: Package: cglib-2.1.3-4.jpp5.noarch (@jpackage-generic) on fresh 2.7 spacewalk install

Tags: spacewalk

I am doing a fresh install of spacewalk 2.7, and when running

```
# yum -y install spacewalk-postgresql
```

i get error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: cglib-2.1.3-4.jpp5.noarch (@jpackage-generic)
Requires: asm >= 1.5.3
Removing: asm-1.5.3-7.jpp5.noarch (@jpackage-generic)
asm = 1.5.3-7.jpp5
Obsoleted By: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
Not found
Error: Package: hibernate3-c3p0-3.6.10-20.sw.noarch (group_spacewalkproject-java-packages)
Requires: mvn(com.mchange:c3p0)
Error: Package: cglib-mvn-2.7.12-1.el7.centos.noarch (group_spacewalkproject-java-packages)
Requires: cglib = 2.2
Installed: cglib-2.1.3-4.jpp5.noarch (@jpackage-generic)
cglib = 2.1.3-4.jpp5
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
YIu could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any clue how i should resolve this ?

Host is Centos 7.4.1708 (Core)

```
# yum versionlock list
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
0:cglib-2.1.3-4.jpp5.*
0:c3p0-0.9.1.2-2.jpp5.*
versionlock list done
```

After removing group_spacewalkproject-java-packages-epel-7.repo
( rename group_spacewalkproject-java-packages-epel-7.repo to group_spacewalkproject-java-packages-epel-7.repo.not.used)

Now when i run yum -y install spacewalk-postgresql

I get:

```
Error: Package: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3-ehcache >= 3.6.10
Error: Package: cglib-2.1.3-4.jpp5.noarch (jpackage-generic)
           Requires: asm >= 1.5.3
           Available: asm-1.5.3-7.jpp5.noarch (jpackage-generic)
               asm = 1.5.3-7.jpp5
Error: Package: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3 >= 3.6.10
           Available: hibernate3-3.2.4-1.SP1_CP01.9.jpp5.noarch (jpackage-generic)
               hibernate3 = 3.2.4-1.SP1_CP01.9.jpp5
Error: Package: spacewalk-taskomatic-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3-ehcache >= 3.6.10
Error: Package: spacewalk-taskomatic-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3-c3p0 >= 3.6.10
Error: Package: spacewalk-taskomatic-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3 >= 3.6.10
           Available: hibernate3-3.2.4-1.SP1_CP01.9.jpp5.noarch (jpackage-generic)
               hibernate3 = 3.2.4-1.SP1_CP01.9.jpp5
Error: Package: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3-c3p0 >= 3.6.10
Error: Package: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: apache-commons-el
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

after i disable group_spacewalkproject-java-packages-epel-7.repo

```
[group_spacewalkproject-java-packages]
name=Copr repo for java-packages owned by @spacewalkproject
baseurl=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@spacewalkproject/java-packages/epel-7-$basearch/
type=rpm-md
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@spacewalkproject/java-packages/pubkey.gpg
repo_gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
enabled_metadata=1
```

and run `yum -y install spacewalk-postgresql` again
i get:

```
Error: Package: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3-ehcache >= 3.6.10
Error: Package: cglib-2.1.3-4.jpp5.noarch (jpackage-generic)
           Requires: asm >= 1.5.3
           Available: asm-1.5.3-7.jpp5.noarch (jpackage-generic)
               asm = 1.5.3-7.jpp5
Error: Package: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3 >= 3.6.10
           Available: hibernate3-3.2.4-1.SP1_CP01.9.jpp5.noarch (jpackage-generic)
               hibernate3 = 3.2.4-1.SP1_CP01.9.jpp5
Error: Package: spacewalk-taskomatic-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3-ehcache >= 3.6.10
Error: Package: spacewalk-taskomatic-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3-c3p0 >= 3.6.10
Error: Package: spacewalk-taskomatic-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3 >= 3.6.10
           Available: hibernate3-3.2.4-1.SP1_CP01.9.jpp5.noarch (jpackage-generic)
               hibernate3 = 3.2.4-1.SP1_CP01.9.jpp5
Error: Package: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: hibernate3-c3p0 >= 3.6.10
Error: Package: spacewalk-java-2.7.116-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk)
           Requires: apache-commons-el
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

-------------------------------------------- Further troubleshooting ---------
installed :

```
c3p0-0.9.2.1-4.el7.noarch.rpm
cglib-2.2-18.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Manually by downloading to the target host, and using rpm -ivh <> to install both packages
Now, when i run

```
yum -y install spacewalk-postgresql
```

I get error:

```
Could not install /root/ssl-build/gss-spacewalk-2-prod.aws.uscis/rhn-org-httpd-ssl-key-pair-gss-spacewalk-2-prod.aws.xx-1.0-1.noarch.rpm at /usr/bin/rhn-install-ssl-cert.pl line 68.
```

This could be due to the fact that this host was a snapshot of another spacewalk server. Need to further resolve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

My environment: Centos 64-bit 7 VMWare

I have the same problem when I am installing the 2.7 version.

Please look at this:

```
https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/spacewalkproject/spacewalk-2.8/
```

As suggested/linked here at github:

```
https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall#installing-spacewalk
```

I deleted the 2.7 based repo of spacewalk then the moment I added the 2.8 repo from fedorainfracloud and perform a "yum update" my initial spacewalk related installations were upgraded to 2.8.

Now I was able to proceed without dependency errors:

```
yum install spacewalk-postgresql
```

[installation success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gZ4U.png)

But with a different error with tomcat:

```
Cobbler requires tftp and xinetd services be turned on for PXE provisioning functionality. Enable these services [Y]?
* Restarting services.
Tomcat failed to start properly or the installer ran out of tries.  Please check /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out or /var/log/tomcat/catalina.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log for errors.
```

To correct this error, I enable and start the tomcat service:

```
systemctl enable tomcat
systemctl start tomcat
/usr/sbin/spacewalk-service start
```

Then I successfully created the user at the spacewalk web console:
[sucess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6cFo.png)